# Running Control Flow Graph Factory plugin from commande line

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I want to run  Control Flow Graph Factory plugin, which is an eclipse plugin that generate a control flow graph from source code (http://www.drgarbage.com/control-flow-graph-factory/), using commande line. My goal is to generate a control flow graph for each method in a java project automatically using this plugin.

Than you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the Control Flow Graph Factory plug-in **can not be run from the command line**.

In the [source code](https://sourceforge.net/p/drgarbagetools/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/) there is

- no definition of an application extension point (for `eclipsec.exe -nosplash -application ...`),
- no Java main method (for `java ...`) and
- no implementation of an Ant task (which can be used in an Ant script).